Compile Time unique hash for variables
is there any ways of making unique hashes for each variable in compile time.
C++ allows block scopes which can result in same named variables inside one function so i cannot just do:
#define MACRO(...) ConstevalHash(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ #__VA_ARGS__)

int variable = 0;
printf("id %d \n", MACRO(variable)); 

in compiled file should look like:
printf("id %d \n", 345908340) // unique hash

I thought of trying to get static memory address of each variable using consteval tricks but im afraid that is not possible with current cpp.
EDIT:
This is solving issue with compile time counters.
Current solution has been just:
#define MACRO(...) __VA_ARGS__.CachedID // static constexpr int CachedID ;

Var<ID, int> Variable = 0; // Id creates unique id using counter
MACRO(variable);

This disallows usage of auto which is not very good solution for any api.
About block scopes
void Function()
{
{ int var = 0; MACRO(var); } 
{ int var = 0; MACRO(var); }
}

while(true)
{
Function();
}


Both of these hashes should be different but they should remain the exact same in every tick inside a loop that's why compile time coding is required.

What is the problem that this code is trying to solve?

sounds like an XY problem.  What are you trying to solve by doing this?


If you exit and reenter a function, do you want to get the same hash or a new one? 2. If you call a function recursively, are its local variables "new" variables or not? Is it ok to get the same hash for them?


std::source_location might get rid of __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, then if you hash from something different than the name of the variable, you might get rid of MACRO.

disallows usage of auto which is not very good solution for any api why? We still don't know what you're trying to achieve, why does each variable need an ID?

"...is there any ways of making unique hashes..." this requirement contains a contradiction as hashes may collide.

Whats wrong with the address of a variable? Hasing a local variable doesn't make much sense to me anyway... Oh see now... you are worried about shadowing? Any good compiler can give you warnings about that, you just need to turn them on

@PepijnKramer -- the address of a local variable is not necessarily unique. void f() { int i = 3; std::cout << i << '\n'; int j = 4; std::cout << j << '\n';}--iandj can have the same address,iisn't used after the introduction ofj, so j` can reuse the same memory.

@PeteBecker i and j can't have the the same address.  They are unique objects so they have unique addresses.  That is addressed here: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.object#10

@NathanOliver -- &i == &j is not valid; can you write a conforming program that can detect that they have the same address? If not, under the as-if rule, it's okay to do it. This is a fairly common optimization.

int i = 3; std::cout << &i << '\n'; int j = 4; std::cout << &j << '\n'; can tell if the addresses are different or not.

@NathanOliver -- the program didn't detect the difference. It just displayed two values. It's the user who detected it, and that's outside the requirements of the standard.

@NathanOliver -- a more rigorous form of the question would be can you write a conforming program that can correctly output either "i and j have the same address" or "j and j have different addresses".

"static memory address of each variable": The fundamental problem is that a non-static variable doesn't have a static memory address.  Its address is only known at run-time, within the block where it's defined, and it can be different on subsequent executions of the same block.

@PeteBecker: Just to be clear, it's not that &i == &j is invalid in general - it's just that by writing it, you are using i after the introduction of j.  So they can be given the same address if and only if the program never checks (in a conforming manner) to see whether their addresses are the same.

@NathanOliver: In practice, I'd expect that code will always show their addresses as different.  Since ostream::operator<< is opaque to the compiler, it has to assume that the address of i has "escaped", and therefore it must actually be given a unique address in memory, in case operator<< has saved that pointer and will make use of it later (still during the lifetime of i, of course).  The same goes for j.  In practice, I expect the only time when i,j will be given the same address is when their addresses are never taken (or if taken, never used in a nontrivial way).

@NathanOliver: And of course, in such a case, they may end up not having addresses at all (kept in registers, or optimized out of existence).

@NateEldredge -- my apologies; I got carried away. &i == &j is, of course, valid. Once you take the address of i or of j the quantum field collapses, and the optimization that I mentioned is no longer valid.

@PeteBecker: You should have added scopes: int* pi; {int i = 3; pi = &i;} int*pj; { int j = 4; pj = &j;}, So both dangling pointers "might" appear to be equal.

I came up with this:
 template <class T> struct var {
     using  hash_type = unsigned;
     using value_type = T;
     
     value_type value;
     const hash_type cached_id;

     constexpr var(const value_type the_value) noexcept 
      : value(the_value)
      , cached_id([]{ static hash_type k; return k++; }())
     {}

     constexpr operator auto() noexcept { return value; }
 };

 template <class T> var(T const&) -> var<T>;

Live on Compiler Explorer
No macros.
Is this what you're looking for?
